# Reverse the words in string

Tags: javascript, algorithm, ecmascript-6

The task:

> Given a string of words delimited by spaces, reverse the words in
>   string. For example, given "hello world here", return "here world
>   hello"
>
> Follow-up: given a mutable string representation, can you perform this
>   operation in-place?

My solution:

```
const reverseStr = s => s.split(' ').reverse().join(' ');

console.log(reverseStr("hello world here"));
```

My "in-place" solution:

```
const reverseStrInPlace = s => {
  let exp = `\\w+$`;
  const startLen = s.lastIndexOf(s.match(/\w+$/)[0]);
  const strLen = s.length;
  const len = (s.match(/\s/g) || []).length;
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    exp = `(\\w+)\\s${exp}`;
    s += ` ${s.match(new RegExp(exp), 'g')[1]}`;
    exp = `(\\w+)\\s${exp}`;
  }
  return s.substring(startLen, startLen + strLen);
}

console.log(reverseStrInPlace('hello world here'));
```

"In-place" algorithms are defined as:

> An in-place algorithm transforms the input without using any extra
>   memory. As the algorithm executes, the input is usually overwritten by
>   the output and no additional space is needed for this operation.

Not sure whether this is the right approach for the in-place solution, because, even though I didn't create for the string a new datastructure, i.e. during the operation I overwrite the input and return the overwritten input as the output, but I created other variables, e.g. `exp`, `len`, `i`, etc. i.e. additional space is created for the operation.

Comment: Array `reverse` is mutating, "in-place" method. Strings are immutable.

Comment: In Javascript strings are a basic type and thus can only be copied. You can not modify a string  inplace.

Comment: Ah, true. In Java as well. How would you have solved it and with what language? @Blindman67

Comment: For performance C or C++, for on the spot solution JavaScript, for when hell freezes over I would create a complicated reverse string class and supporting eco in Java, cut of my ARM, and cry. Sorry I hate Java and would never use it unless there was absolutely no other option (which is never the case)

Comment: Why do you hate Java so much? @Blindman67

Comment: Long and complicated history of disappointment and frustration. Main reason, the VM, it's full of holes and why use a low level like language that needs a JIT compiler. There are very few apps that need to run on every machine under there sun, and if you do, modern C/C++ compilers can compile to more targets than there are Java VM

Comment: @Blindman67 I guess I have to experience these frustration myself yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript, strings are [immutable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Character_access)

> For character access using bracket notation, attempting to delete or assign a value to these properties will not succeed. The properties involved are neither writable nor configurable. (See [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) for more information.)

So this was either a trick question or the creator was not aware.

The only "mutable string representation" of a javascript string would be an array.

So if the question accepts using an array as the representation of the string, you could do something like this:

```js
function reverse(str){
  const mutable = str.split("");
  
  for(let i = 0; i < mutable.length/2; i++){
    const j = mutable.length-1-i;
    const c = mutable[i];
    mutable[i] = mutable[j];
    mutable[j] = c;
  }
  
  return mutable.join("");
}

const res = reverse("hello world");

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Good idea to loop only to the middle of the array!

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I am not a JavaScripter.

The `exp` grows inside the loop, and is not bound by a constant; ditto for `s`. This immediately disqualifies the solution as in-place. Besides, the time complexity (as it matches the growing string in the loop) seems quadratic.

A true in-place algorithm, with linear time complexity, starts with reversing the entire string:

```
ereh dlrow olleh
```

Now the words are in the desired order, but are themselves reversed. The only thing left is to reverse individual words.

Implementing a linear time in-place (sub)string reversal is left as an exercise.

Comment: Then I guess this is not possible to solve in JS, Because reversing you need either a new array or a new string. (in JS strings are immutable; not sure how you could emulate this in JS and how it would look differently than the first solution in my OP)

Comment: @thadeuszlay In the wild (say, during an interview) I would accept converting a string to an array first. After all, it is the algorithmic question.